# Installing phpMyAdmin on Cent OS 5.5

Tags: linux, php, centos5

This is installed on CentOs 5.5

Please bare in mind that this is on a local network at work and access from the outside world is not possible due to the strict restrictions on the local network.

I have managed to get php 5.3 installed on the linux box, however I am having great difficulty in setting up phpmyadmin, no matter what I do I can't get it to work.

phpMyAdmin is in /usr/share/phpMyAdmin and I have an Alias in phpMyAdmin.conf which is called into the httpd.conf file.

This is the Alias's that I am using:

Alias /phpmyadmin "/usr/share/phpMyAdmin"
Alias /phpMyAdmin "/usr/share/phpMyAdmin"
Alias /mysqladmin "/usr/share/phpMyAdmin"

I have warn you that I only really started using ssh for the last 2 days so I am a linux newbie.

I appreciate any help I can get.

Thanks in advance, Jon

Comment: what happens when you try to access phpmyadmin page ? it prints php ? it reply with a 500 error ? have you done yum install phpmyadmin ? also have you tried any simple php page to see if your php installation was succefull

Comment: By trying to access the http://ip_here/phpmyadmin I get the following error...
You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin on this server.

I have tried yum install phpmyadmin and it won't install because of dependencies which I can't find a repository for.

The PHP works as I can output phpinfo on a .php page.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***UPDATE***

I have now managed to get it working on the localhost, so I guess now I just need to get it working from a remote machine.

Comment: Fixed the problem now... I uninstalled all instances of php / mysql / phpmyadmin, reinstalled... Set the owner of phpmyadmin to apache.apache changed the phpMyAdmin.conf to allow from all and everything seems to be working now.

Thanks everyone for the help, but I have now managed to work it now.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe "/usr/share/phpMyAdmin" was created by root user and apache user can't access it.

As root type:

```
chown -R apache.apache /usr/share/phpMyAdmin
service httpd restart
```

Comment: This is something that I have tried, and still not helped... Apologies for not adding that to my question :(

Comment: Did you restart apache service? What returns ls -ld /usr/share/phpMyAdmin?

Comment: I did restart apache and this is what it returned drwxr-xr-x 11 apache apache 4096 Aug  5 10:52 /usr/share/phpMyAdmin

Comment: What does tell Apache logs? /var/log/httpd/error.log or /var/log/messages (grep httpd)

Comment: Instance of the error in error_log is: [Thu Aug 05 12:02:26 2010] [error] [client 192.168.1.94] (13)Permission denied: access to /phpMyAdmin denied

Answer (score 0):

Try to look into your phpMyAdmin.conf if you have something like this:

```
<Directory/usr/share/phpMyAdmin>
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 127.0.0.1
</Directory>
```

That would actually say that you cannot access phpMyAdmin from a remote computer, I would remove that bit and test first and then let us know if that work or not.

Comment: This isn't in my .conf file, only the 3 Alias's mentioned above are in there.

Comment: I just tried this:

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin>
order deny,allow
allow from 127.0.0.1
allow from 192.168.1.94
</Directory>

Answer (score 0):

Something is set in your httpd.conf that is not allowing the alias to resolve correctly.  Other than that, try adding a trailing slash to the URL:  http://localhost/phpmyadmin/

Comment: In fact, upon checking directly on the server itself, you can't even access phpmyadmin via localhost... Now I am truely baffled. Trailing slash didn't work.. I guess I need to filter through the entire httpd.conf but I am unsure what I would be looking for to be honest.